# Type of connector for PCB project

Tags: pcb, connector, identification, pins

Can anyone tell me which type of pins are on the picture [image: here]
and [image: here]? I would like to use the same type o connector for my pcb project but with less pins. 10 in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Board-to-board compression connector*. Examples: [Molex](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=compression_connectors&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=board_to_board_connectors), [TE Connectivity](http://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/compression-headers-receptacles/Y30nK.html).

Comment: What about connector on first pic, is it on pcb or is it some connecotr type?

Comment: @JaksaTomovic looks like a battery to me.